# prevention of additional eventListeners being added to a dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to ensure that no more event listeners are added to a particular element(in js). Due to template I have chosen after certain actions there are some event handlers being added to a particular element which contain lines like `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` which hinders my work .Since I can't remove these lines is there any way with which I can prevent an eventHandler being attached to an element?

Comment: This sounds quite strange. A specific example of what you're trying to do would help a lot. What's the purpose of not allowing more listeners? Do you want an error to be thrown when that happens so you can go to the code there and refactor, or what?

Comment: I am trying to register click elements throughout that div but because of this additional eventListener being added the click element is not bubbling all the way to the other elements

Comment: Ah, so you want to prevent *that* listener from being added, so that other parts of your code can work?

Comment: An extreme hack would be to change the element so, that those other event listeners can't be attached. Change the tagname, class, id ... what ever the other code uses to refer the element. In hard cases you could even append the element to a new place in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hacky, but if you can run code before the bad event listener code runs, you can temporarily change `addEventListener` to a no-op, then change it back afterwards:

```js
// Inject this first:
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = () => {
  console.log('Refusing to add bad event listener');
  delete HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
};

// Then the attachment of the bad listener will fail:
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Bad listener running');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

console.log('Bad code finished, now adding good event listeners again');
// And your other listeners that want to be able to see the event will succeed:
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Saw click on body');
});
```

```html
<div id="container">click me</div>
```

A more elaborate method would be to examine the source of the passed function string to see if it contains `preventDefault` (or exactly matches what you want to not get attached).

An alternative which *doesn't* involve preventing the attachment of that listener is to add your own listeners in the capturing phase, before the event propagation gets stopped:

```js
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Bad listener running');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

console.log('Bad code finished, now adding good event listeners again');
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Saw click on body');
}, true); // <---- pass 3rd parameter of true to listen in capturing phase
```

```html
<div id="container">click me</div>
```